# Regex Delimiters Failing to Work in preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a bunch of phone numbers to sort through and am trying to use regex to identify phone numbers and separate them from some junk data that has been mixed in. To achieve this, I am using `preg_match()` with the pattern below:

```
$pattern = '/(\(?\d{3}\)?\s*[\-\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-\.]?\s*\d{4})/';
```

Despite the regex being enclosed by `/`, `preg_match()` is identifying part of the regex as a modifier, returning an error:

> Unknown modifier ']'

Why is `preg_match()` ignoring the delimters and interpreting `]` as a modifier?

Here is the context:

```
    $pattern = '/(\(?\d{3}\)?\s*[\-\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-\.]?\s*\d{4})/';
    $matches;
    while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $tel = $record['PHONENUMBER'];
        $tel_count++;
        if(strlen($tel) >= 7){
            preg_match($pattern, $tel, $matches);
            $valid_tel_count += sizeof($matches);
            if(sizeof($matches) > 1){
                $overpacked_tel_count++;
            }
            for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($matches); $i++){
                //echo($matches[$i].'; ');
            }
            //echo('<br />');
        }
        else{
            $invalid_tel_count++;
            if(strlen($tel) == 0 || $tel == ''){
                $empty_tel_count++;
            }
            else{
                var_dump($tel);
                echo('<br />');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Your regex works fine](https://3v4l.org/qdOE1) .. I don't see this error: *Unknown modifier ']'*

Comment: Where is your actual call to `preg_match()` ? Additionally, you do not need to escape the dot in square brackets: `~(\(?\d{3}\)?\s*[-.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[-.]?\s*\d{4})~`.

Comment: I'll post more of the code

Comment: Are you using PHP 7?

Comment: Parses fine and is no error.

Comment: One more ["works fine"](http://ideone.com/KRqTE5).

Comment: You could even use `'~(\(?\d{3}\)?\s*[\-\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-\.]?\s*\d{4})~'` for contrast.

Comment: It's hard to imagine any engine would give this message `modifier ']'`

Comment: The tildes worked! I'm surprised, because I tried using other delimiters and they weren't working.

Comment: Grab this [app](http://www.regexformat.com) and use _MegaString_ to construct production regex strings.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @sln. I tried changing the delimiters back to slashes and it threw a compilation error `preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses` instead. I'm suspicious this might be a bug in php's engine. PHP version 5.5.30 on OS X 10.11.2 if anyone wants to look into it. For now, I'll just use the tilde.

Comment: I can't imagine a valid engine screwing up the parse of delimiters. And, I wouldn't trust that version of php. Try re-install and see if the error persist. One thing to note about delimiters, you want to avoid use of a delimiter(s) that are already escaped in the raw regex. This is mostly true for metacharacters. Example raw `///\//` becomes `'/\/\/\/\/\//'` which parses to `/////`